# OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_IMAGES and OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_SETUP does not show any output

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I've tried to use OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_IMAGES and OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_SETUP environmental variables on Objective-C executable in order to learn about vtable mechanism in Objective-C objects. Unfortunately the mentioned environment variables have no effect on console output, despite the fact that runtime acknowledged that the variables were set:

```
» OBJC_PRINT_OPTIONS=1 OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_IMAGES=YES /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
objc[41098]: OBJC_PRINT_OPTIONS is set
objc[41098]: OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_IMAGES is set
```

I've tried to use both variables on executables provided by system (TextEdit) and my own. With no effect.

Whole vtable mechanism in Objective-C objects is obscure. It's hard to find information about this mechanism on Apple pages. There is some info from other sources, but no official documentation:
http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2011/06/17/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_vtable.html
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html

Why these variables are not working? Does vtables in current version of Objective-C are deprecated?

Comment: If you didn't know, the objective-c runtime is open-source. These kinds of questions can usually be answered by looking at the implementation: https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10124.html

Comment: In this case, it looks like vtable and fixup dispatch are synonymous - and fixup dispatch was deprecated in OSX 10.8. https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-709/runtime/objc-abi.h.auto.html, see line 247.

Comment: Also, in objc-msg-x86_64.s, it would appear that msgSend_fixup is just an `INT 3` instruction (SIGTRAP), meaning anything that attempted to use it on a modern version of OS X would probably crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the answer is pretty straightforward - vtable dispatch is no longer optimized in the objective-c runtime, and was probably a bad idea in the first place.

vtable-based dispatch was one of the first attempts to speed up frequent calls in the objective-c runtime, but note that it predates the current method caching solution. The problem with using a fixed set of selectors as in the vtable solution not only means increased memory for *every class in the runtime*, but it also means that if you're using an architecture which doesn't result in `isEqualToString:` being called frequently, for example, you now have a completely wasted pointer for *EVERY* class in the runtime that overrides ONE of those selectors. Whoops.

Also, note that Vtable dispatch by design couldn't work on 32-bit architectures, which meant that once the iOS SDK was released, and 32bit was again a reasonable target for objective-c, that optimization simply couldn't work.

The relevant documentation that I can find for this is in [`objc-abi.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-709/runtime/objc-abi.h.auto.html):

```
#if TARGET_OS_OSX  &&  defined(__x86_64__)
// objc_msgSend_fixup() is used for vtable-dispatchable call sites.
OBJC_EXPORT void objc_msgSend_fixup(void)
    __OSX_DEPRECATED(10.5, 10.8, "fixup dispatch is no longer optimized") 
    __IOS_UNAVAILABLE __TVOS_UNAVAILABLE __WATCHOS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Nowadays, there aren't many vestigial fragments of vtable dispatch left in the runtime. A quick grep over the codebase shows a few places in `objc-runtime-new.mm`:

```
#if SUPPORT_FIXUP
    // Fix up old objc_msgSend_fixup call sites
    for (EACH_HEADER) {
        message_ref_t *refs = _getObjc2MessageRefs(hi, &count);
        if (count == 0) continue;

        if (PrintVtables) {
            _objc_inform("VTABLES: repairing %zu unsupported vtable dispatch "
                         "call sites in %s", count, hi->fname());
        }
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fixupMessageRef(refs+i);
        }
    }

    ts.log("IMAGE TIMES: fix up objc_msgSend_fixup");
#endif
```

And

```
*********************************************************************
* fixupMessageRef
* Repairs an old vtable dispatch call site. 
* vtable dispatch itself is not supported.
**********************************************************************/
static void 
fixupMessageRef(message_ref_t *msg)
```

Which pretty clearly indicates that it's not supported.

See also, the method stub for it (if you were to do it without a compiler generated call-site), found in `objc-msg-x86_64.s`:

```
ENTRY _objc_msgSend_fixup
int3
END_ENTRY _objc_msgSend_fixup
```

Where `int3` is the SIGTRAP instruction, which would cause a crash if a debugger isn't attached (usually).

So, while vtable dispatch is an interesting note in the history of objective-c, it should be looked back as little more than an experiment when we weren't quite familiar with the best ways to optimize common method calls.

Comment: One final note - the Vtable wasn't on the objects themself (like in C++), but on the *class* of the object. Because objective-c already had metatypes, there was no real reason to do the vtables at the object level like C++ does. It does mean there's an extra level of indirection (and cache misses), which probably also didn't help vtables case once method caching was around.

Comment: Thank you for such complete explanation. Are there any resources you could recommend (minus source code itself) which keep track about non-trivial implementation changes in Objective-C?

Comment: @MichałZabielski not that I know of. It would make an interesting project though, if I had the spare time. One day, perhaps.